# regexp_split_to_table to split my column on 2 different levels

Tags: postgis, regular-expression

[image]

Hi Guys is it possible to use regexp_split_to_table to split my column on 2 different levels. AS in split by ';' and then split by ' '.
I have this "-29.617356578819454 30.394328366965055 0.0 0.0;-29.61735976394266 30.39434471167624 0.0 0.0;" a column called "RPT_FTR_TRACE". ; seperates each coordinates and a space seperate long from lat.
I want regexp_split_to_table to split it for me so my final query have "-29.617356578819454 30.394328366965055 0.0 0.0; in one column and long=-29.617356578819454 column and lat= 30.394328366965055 column

```
WITH a AS (
         SELECT DISTINCT "_URI",
            "_SUBMISSION_DATE","INFO_TEAM_NAME","INFO_SUPERVISOR_NAME","INFO_LOCATION","RPT_FTR_WIDTH",
            "RPT_FTR_TRACE" AS t
           FROM odk_duct.duct_monitoring_core
        )/* selection from odk_duct.duct_monitoring_core table,*/ 
    ,b AS (
    SELECT a."_URI",
           a."_SUBMISSION_DATE",initcap(a."INFO_TEAM_NAME"),"RPT_FTR_TRACE",
           b.p,
           b.id

           FROM odk_duct.duct_monitoring_core a,
           LATERAL regexp_split_to_table("RPT_FTR_TRACE", ';'::text) WITH ORDINALITY b(p, id)
           WHERE b.p <> ''::text
            ) select * from b
```

Comment: It would be much better to edit the question with actual SQL (and maybe less decimal places :-)). Screen shots are very unpleasant to try and understand.

Comment: you can use (string to array) for that to insert lat, lon in separate columns. I can add a query for that if you like

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça i have included the sql.

Comment: @User2009 please add a query so i see and understand what you mean

Comment: You mean something like what I did for you in your last question? You should be able to use the same technique for regexp to table also the second round. But I used regexp_to_array in second round. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279872/960

Comment: Hi @NicklasAvén exactly but i wanted to split by ';' semi colon and after split by ' ' space. You helped with the split by semi colon. Wanted to see if its possible to split by both  semi colon and a space in the same query

Comment: If you see a little bit further down in the query you find: 
 regexp_split_to_array(p,' ') as coord_array. That is exactly what is happening there :-)